# function runs well line by line with specified i's but does not work with function call

Tags: r, function, sapply

```
FUNC <- function(i){
var <- i
dist <- sapply(1:(i-1),function(x){list[[x]]*co[var,x]})
mean <- sapply(1:(i-1),FUN2)
block <- t(co[i,i]*list[[i]])+rowSums(mean)
new_list[[i]] <- t(block)
}
```

When I specify i=4, or i=10, and run the code inside the function definition line by line, it totally works and assigns `new_list[[i]]` the value of `t(block)`.
however, when I do

```
FUNC(4) or FUNC(10)
```

It returns the error message

```
Error in dist[[x]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone have any idea why it wouldn't work with a function call?
Thank you!!

Comment: There are several objects that are undefined, which will make helping you very difficult. The programming style you're using here is very strange. Can you update your question with some sample data and explain what you are trying to accomplish in English? I'm guessing there is a much more efficient way to accomplish what you've got going on here. FWIW, I get a `Error in list[[x]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable` error when trying to run your code as `FUNC(4)`.

Comment: Also, we don't know what `co` is, what `FUN2` is, and where and how `new_list` is defined....

Comment: Also [assignments within a function call are temporary](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Assignment-within-functions)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your `FUN2` function uses `dist`. But the `dist` you calculate inside `FUNC` is local, so `FUN2` can't find it. Instead, it uses the one in your global workspace, which is probably too short. That's why you get that error message.

You should really change both `FUNC` and `FUN2` so they don't use any global variables (`co`, `dist`, `list`, `new_list` - and possibly `FUN2` too could be arguments to `FUNC`).

...but at least change `FUN2` to take `dist` as an argument:

```
FUN2 <- function(i, dist) {
  # Your code here...
}

# In FUNC: Pass dist to FUN2
mean <- sapply(1:(i-1),FUN2, dist=dist)
```

...And if this code is something you want to keep around, you should **REALLY** consider giving the functions more descriptive names...

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that was the problem. I know it is hard to do from what I have provided, but can you think of any more efficient way to do this? the list has more than 1000 elements and it takes forever to run the code. Thanks

Comment: @MillyVanilli - Well, update your question with what the overall goal is and what FUN2 looks like! ...and some sample data would be nice too.

Comment: +1 for being able to figure it out from that little information.

Comment: @BrianDiggs: Psychic debugging!